# Is it possible to count numbers of visitors for hide/show?

Tags: jquery

Within my website I will have items as a list. And these items will not have their own page. They will be in a hide/show style and when I show any item in the list, the content of it will be seen (naturally).

The thing I would like to learn is: can I count the numbers of visitors for these items, how many times any item has been clicked?

Regards

Comment: if you are using a database, you can have one table to store the number of times a link was clicked. Or you can use a simple text file too. You can achieve it with help of AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

Sure setup a php script and a database, do these "items" have id's or some sort of unique identifiers? You could do something like:

```
$('opener').click(function(e) {
    //jquery ajax request to a script, passing the identifier of the item
    $.get("count.php?id="+this.id);
});
```

you could grab that id in php, and update a database with a new number of views

Comment: Thank you Mike L. It will help me!